# Strange Wireshark behaviour (A single packet labeled both TCP and UDP)

Tags: tcp, udp, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a big PCAP file downloaded from [this website](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/captures.html). (You can [download the original pcap file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/tcpreplay-pcap-files/bigFlows.pcap) : 368 MBs)

You can also [download a short version that contains only some of the buggy packets](http://bayanbox.ir/info/4298941656202879125/test).

There is something strange with some packets inside this file. There are 1113 packets labeled with `sFlow` inside it that it doesn't matters which wireshark-filter you apply to the packets, you always will see them (or part of them) in the window:

To be more clear let see some screen shots:

**No filter applied:**
[image]

**Filter to see `tcp` packets only:**
[image]

**Filter to see `udp` packets only:**
[image]

**Filter to see packets with `ip.addr == 68.64.21.64`**
[image]

What's wrong with these packets?

Comment: completely off topic here, but either way, the packets themselves simply _cannot_ be both UDP and TCP because there's a single 8 bit field in the IP header that indicates which it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These packets are of [sFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFlow) type. They are used for network sampling, so they contain samples of other network packets within. Display filter seems to be applied not only to sFlow packet itself, but to every inner packet as well. So "tcp" display filter leaves those sFlow packets (they are obviously udp), which contain tcp sample within. Same for address filtering.

You can inspect inner packets as shown on the picture[image: sFlow inner packet]

Not sure if filter behavior is correct, I was amused by output as well. I think, it'd be great to open ticket at [Wireshark bug database](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/) to hear developers' opinion.

Comment: Wireshark display filters work like Boolean operators in that if the expression is true, then the packet is displayed; if it's false then it's not displayed.  This means that if **any** field within the packet matches the filter then the packet will be displayed.  This behavior is intentional and completely expected.